# SpringBoot com hibernate e relacionamento entre tabelas postgres em diferentes schemas

Tags: postgresql, hibernate, spring-boot

estou com o seguinte problema:
cirei um banco chamado Teste e dentro tem dois schemas: schema1 e schema2.
Dentro de cada schema tem uma tabela:
schema1 -> tabela1
schema2 -> tabela2

Acontece que se tento fazer um relacionamento com SpringBoot usando annotations entre a tabela1 e tabela2, elas nao se enxergam. com sql puro, consigo, basta informar a tabela com schema.
schema1.tabela1
schema2.tabela2.

Mas como faco isso o Spring Boot? eis me codigo.

```
@Entity @Table(schema = "schema_1") 
public class Tabela1 implements Serializable {
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY) 
private Integer id;
private String name;
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "tabela1")
private List<Tabela2> tabela2= new ArrayList<>();
publicTabela1() {
    }
 }
```

segunda tabela

```
@Entity    
@Table(schema = "schema_2")
public class Tabela2 implements Serializable {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Integer id;
private String number;
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "fk_tabela1")
private Tabela1 tabela1;
public Tabela2() {
         }
     }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Na classe Tabela1, você pode precisa mapear o schema para a classe Tabela2 utilizando a propriedade "targetEntity":

```
@OneToMany(targetEntity=Tabela2.class, mappedBy = "tabela1") 
private List tabela2= new ArrayList();
```

Comment: Funcionou perfeitamente. Muito obrigado

Comment: @RodrigoBatista, se a resposta ajudou, marque a resposta do colega como a correta :)